# Zipping a folder in linux gives different size with different user

Tags: linux, unix, zip, gzip, tar

I have a folder which i want to create tgz file and compute its sha256:

The folder is converted to tgz using following command

```
 "tar -c -C #{Shellwords.escape dir} #{Shellwords.escape basename} " \
        "--owner=0 --group=0 --mtime='2000-01-01 00:00:00' | gzip -n > #{Shellwords.escape file}"
```

Now i ran the above process using 2 separate users and it gave me 2 files: 1 and 2

Both tgz files differ in sizes:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 myuser  \Domain Users  9024 Jul 31 14:28 1.tgz
-rw-r--r--@ 1 myuser  \Domain Users  9037 Jul 31 14:29 2.tgz
```

If i try to compute diff between files i dont see any diff.Diff was obtained using following command.

```
diff  <(tar -tvf 1.tgz | sort) <(tar -tvf 2.tgz | sort)
```

If i compute sha256 using ruby of these 2 files , then it differs.

The question is : Why do i get difference in tgz files when running from different users.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is a programming question only.

Answer (score 0):

the differences are in the headers, the header of each file in a tar contains the user and group id. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Header .

Also modern tar adds additional data called Ustar to the header:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#UStar_format
which contains also the owner username.

try:

```
diff  <(gunzip -c 1.tgz | xxd) <(gunzip -c 1.tgz | xxd)
```

and you'll see the difference